# Random integer with specific range: values are getting greater than max value

Tags: javascript, random

I need a random integer in a specific range from `100` to `screenHeight - 400`.

The code is as follows ,but why are there values greater than the max value?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const   screenHeight = $(document).height(),
            max  = screenHeight - 400,
            min  = 100,
            y    = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

    console.log(max, y, y > max);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the factor for getting the right interval.

```
 y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 //                             ^    ^^^^^^
```